# Save Visual Studio Debug -> Exceptions settings?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, exception, configuration, ide

I find that in different cases you need to have different exception classes enabled/disabled in the Debug -> Exceptions dialog, and it's hard work to keep reconfiguring this.

So, is there any way to save the Debug -> Exception setting and restore them later?

I'd like to have a couple of different configurations to load depending on my needs.

I am aware that the settings are stored in SlnName.suo, but so are a lot of other stuff and it's a daunting and risky task to fiddle with it.

The question refers to Visual Studio 2010, but I'd be interested to know if the dialog has been improved in this respect in later versions of VS.

Comment: The best option I was able to think of (and I've looked for VS extensions doing so)  , is to record several macros that record the specific steps you are doing for each one of the scenarios. then you can configure a keyboard shortcut or button for each one of them for quick changes. what do you think about this option?

Comment: Ouch! Nice out-of-the-box thinking! Too much work I think, but I'll certainly keep that idea in mind in case I get desperate enough. :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to the following article:

https://faithlife.codes/blog/2010/01/saving_debug_exceptions_settings/

*"These settings are stored in the SolutionName.suo file that lives alongside your .sln file. Once you’ve configured the Exceptions dialog to your liking, close all the open windows, then exit Visual Studio. Make a backup of the .suo file and restart Visual Studio. Whenever VS loses your settings, close it down, overwrite the real .suo file with your backup, restart VS, and you’re back to debugging the way you want to."*